# Passing selected polygon to INTERSECTS filter in a WFS request

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wfs, filter

In the code below,

```
   <ogc:Filter>
     <ogc:Intersects>
       <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
       <ogc:Function name="querySingle">
          <ogc:Literal>sf:restricted</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>the_geom</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>cat = 3</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
     </ogc:Intersects>
   </ogc:Filter>
```

I'd like to replace

```
   <ogc:Literal>sf:restricted</ogc:Literal>
   <ogc:Literal>the_geom</ogc:Literal>
   <ogc:Literal>cat = 3</ogc:Literal>
```

with a polygon selected by a user. I get the polygon from a selection event. I've tried a number of options, but none is working, yet. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

My environment: GeoServer 2.1.3, OpenLayers 2.11.

---

I've transformed my geometry to `EPSG:4326`, the one used by my layers in GeoServer:

```
var geometry = event.feature.geometry.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
```

The `event.feature.geometry` represents a polygon selected by a user.
I've also converted the geometry to `WKT` format as shown below:

```
var wktParser = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector();
feature.geometry = geometry;

var wktGeom = wktParser.write(feature);
```

I've then passed the geometry in `WKT` format to the filter as shown below:

```
'<ogc:Filter>' +
'<ogc:Intersects>' +
    '<ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>' +
    '<ogc:Function name="querySingle">' +
        '<ogc:Literal>ws:layer_2</ogc:Literal>' +
        '<ogc:Literal>the_geom</ogc:Literal>' +
        '<ogc:Literal>INTERSECTS(the_geom,' + wktGeom + ')</ogc:Literal>' +
    '</ogc:Function>' +
'</ogc:Intersects>' +
'</ogc:Filter>';
```

But when I send a request, the following error is returned:

`<ows:ExceptionText>Process failed during execution
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.geotools.filter.AttributeExpressionImpl cannot be cast to org.opengis.filter.Filter
org.geotools.filter.AttributeExpressionImpl cannot be cast to org.opengis.filter.Filter</ows:ExceptionText>`.

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/cql/cql.html

So the third parameter would be something like:

INTERSECTS(ATTR1, POLYGON((... )) )

The polygon has to be expressed in the WKT syntax and be in the same SRS as the layer being queried. Either that, or get a recent GeoServer version and call setSRS(POLYGON(...), 'EPSG:xywz') around the WKT (that function has been added May 27 so it should be in 2.1.4 but not earlier versions)

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I've tried your suggestion: I've transformed my projection and converted the polygon to wkt representation. Refer to the updated question above. But I get a `ClassCastException` when I send a request. Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: You added single quotes around the geometry WTK, there should be none. Not sure this is the reason for the issue though

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, its not a quote. Rather, I'm concatenating strings, and passing in the value of `wktGeom`.

Comment: Its now working. I was using the inbuilt `toWKT()` function. It worked when I manually did the conversion to `WKT`. Thanks.